# Como pega objetos de uma array, com filtro passando como parâmetro um objeto com múltiplos ID's

Tags: javascript, array, angularjs, filtro

Associando o objeto "categorias" em "produtos"; Com os ID que preciso associar a tal produto, assim por exemplo "produtos 1" deve receber as "categorias" com o ID [1, 3, 4]. criando uma outra array combinando os dados entre estes objeto.

```
{
    "produtos": [{
        "id": 1,
            "nome": "Produto 1",
            "categorias": [1, 3, 4]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
            "nome": "Produto 2",
            "categorias": [1, 2, 5]
    }, {
        "id": 3,
            "nome": "Produto 3",
            "categorias": [3, 1, 4]
    }],
        "categorias": [{
        "id": 1,
            "nome": "Categoria 1"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
            "nome": "Categoria 2"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
            "nome": "Categoria 3"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
            "nome": "Categoria 4"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
            "nome": "Categoria 5"
    }]
}
```

Resultado array:
    {
        "produtos": [
{
            "id": 1,
                "nome": "Produto 1",
                "categorias": [
                   {"id" : 1, "nome" : "Categoria 1"}, {"id" : 3, "nome" : "Categoria 3"}, {"id" : 4, "nome" : "Categoria 4"} ]
        }
]

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que tem no titulo? está pouco clara  o que quer fazer...

Comment: Com objeto "categorias" em "produtos" com os ID que preciso associar a tal produto, assim por exemplo "produtos 1" deve mostrar as "categorias" com o ID [1, 3, 4].

Comment: Ainda está pouco claro... Pode fazer [edit]ar na pergunta e juntar mais info? não percebo o que quer dizer com "deve mostrar" e "com filtro". Quer gerar HTML ou criar uma outra array combinando os dados este objeto?

Comment: Pode juntar um exemplo de como deve ser o resultado final?

Comment: @Sergio, fiz a alteração, é algo como associar o objeto categorias a o objeto produtos, onde eu tenho os ID das categorias das quais será combinadas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se percebí bem o que quer fazer teste assim:

```js
var json = { "produtos": [{ "id": 1, "nome": "Produto 1", "categorias": [1, 3, 4] }, { "id": 2, "nome": "Produto 2", "categorias": [1, 2, 5] }, { "id": 3, "nome": "Produto 3", "categorias": [3, 1, 4] }], "categorias": [{ "id": 1, "nome": "Categoria 1" }, { "id": 2, "nome": "Categoria 2" }, { "id": 3, "nome": "Categoria 3" }, { "id": 4, "nome": "Categoria 4" }, { "id": 5, "nome": "Categoria 5" }] };

json = (function () {
    json.produtos.forEach(function (produtoObjeto) {
        produtoObjeto.categorias = produtoObjeto.categorias.map(function(id) {
            var categoria = json.categorias.filter(function(objeto) {
                return objeto.id == id;
            })[0];
            return categoria;
        });
    })
    return json;
})();
alert(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4));
```

Dividindo por partes o que o código faz:

- `json.produtos.forEach(function (produtoObjeto) {`

Itera sobre a array de produtos

- `produtoObjeto.categorias = produtoObjeto.categorias.map(function(id) {`

vai mapear a array de categorias dentro de cada produto. Vai trocar cada numero dentro dessa array pelo objeto correspondente na array das categorias.

- `var categoria = json.categorias.filter(function(objeto) {`

dentro da array das categorias o `.filter()` vai retornar somente aquela que tiver a ID certa

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio, era exatamente isso, passei dias, procurando soluções, desde já muito obrigado.